# Deserialize nested class into primitive property type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have sample json that looks like:

```
{
    "isError": false,
    "Status": 0,
    "Message": "The request processed successfully.",
    "Result": [
        {
            "EmployeeId": {
                "DisplayValue": "XX11"
            },
            "Title": {
                "DisplayValue": "M"
            },
            "FirstName": {
                "DisplayValue": "J"
            },
            "LastName": {
                "DisplayValue": "E"
            }
       }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for a setting or a custom converter that collapses the nested classes into their respective properties.

i.e

```
public string EmployeeId {get; set;}
```

So in the above example the value assigned would be: "XX11"

I have been playing around with for a little while and now i need some help.

Is this supported out of the box or do you have to write a custom converter for it?

Comment: what value do you want it to have?

Comment: *"I am looking for a setting or a custom converter that collapses the nested classes into their respective properties."* what does that mean? It isn't entirely clear. Do you mean you should end up with `EmployeeId == "XX11"`? In other words, you end up with a property with the `DisplayValue`

Comment: @DanielA.White, should be "XX11" for EmployeeId.

Comment: You should separate the deserialization structures from what you need in your application. Create types that mimic the structure of the json file, then create a separate set of structures and an adapter. This will make it heaps easier to get what you want.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I have that = ) but was hoping a converter might be quicker and more efficient and less code to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve this problem is to write a `JsonConverter` that acts at the property level to flatten the "DisplayValue" object down to its value.  This is actually very straightforward:

```
public class DisplayValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return (string)obj["DisplayValue"];
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you would need to add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to each property in your `Result` class which needs to be flattened.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public bool isError { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DisplayValueConverter))]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DisplayValueConverter))]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DisplayValueConverter))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DisplayValueConverter))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize the JSON into the `RootObject` class and it should "just work":

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0L9sjl

Answer (score 1):

converting your json to class i got this structure:

```
public class EmployeeId
    {
        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Title
    {
        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstName
    {
        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastName
    {
        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public EmployeeId EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Title Title { get; set; }
        public FirstName FirstName { get; set; }
        public LastName LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool isError { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
    }
```

To deserialize either you can use

```
var res1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json); // Newton.json dll
           JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // System.Web.Script.Serialization
           var res2 = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah that's what you get by default, but the FirstName and related classes are useless, as they have one property in them, the DisplayValue property. Hence the need for this question. These nested classes should be demoted down to primitive types where possible. So i was hoping someone could show me the basics of what I need to write a custom converter to do this for me.